# Dynamically setting the table layout

Tags: java, android, android-tablelayout

I am trying to dynamically set a table layout in an activity. The number of rows and columns depend upon the user's input.

**So the problem** - Every time number of rows are fine but number of columns (textViews) in each row is always equal to the lowest value of the array `no_periods[ ]`. For eg. if no_days has a value 5, `no_periods[]` have 2, 3, 4, 5, 6 values. The table will have 5 rows but each row will have only 2 textViews instead of 2, 3, 4, 5, 6 textViews in the respective rows.

Here is the code I am trying with

```
        //loop to set the rows and text view in the table layout of activity_home  
    for (int i = 0; i < no_days; i++) {

    tableRow = new TableRow(TimeTable.this);

    for (int j = 0; j <no_periods[i]; j++) {

       textView = new TextView(TimeTable.this);
               textView.setHint("Click");
               textView.setClickable(true);
               textView.setOnClickListener(click_listen);

               int maxpixels = screenWidth/(no_periods[i]);
               int minpixels = maxpixels; 

               textView.setPadding(10, 10, 10, 10);

               textView.setMaxWidth(maxpixels);
               textView.setMinWidth(minpixels);

               tableRow.addView(textView);

           }
           tableLayout.addView(tableRow);

       }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of setting max and minWidth, use TableRow **weight**:

```
textView.setPadding(10, 10, 10, 10);

tableRow.addView(textView, new TableRow.LayoutParams(LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, 1));
```

This will distribute horizontal space among the TextViews in each row.

PS. You will probably want to use `textView.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER);` too.

Comment: sorry posted wrong here. I did no_subjects only. Can u please help further

Comment: please explain why my method was wrong. Also if I replace the no_periods[i] with a constant value, I get a rows with equal number of textViews equal to that constant value

Comment: @Abhinav Unless you set it, the number of columns is determined by the _first_ row you add. So you could set it to the maximum and it would work. However, from your code I assumed you wanted to distribute all the width in each row amongst the views, is that not the case?

Comment: Sir, I did try setting the no. of columns of first row as 3 and then 2nd row as 2 and then consecutive row's value > 2. But the whole table then had 2 columns(the lowest value of no_periods[]). Also, yes as each row had different no of columns I wanted to distribute the width among those columns equally

Comment: @Abhinav looks like a textbook case for using weights then. :-)